# How to write statement bindings for C++ 14 Compiler

Tags: c++

```
 warning: structured bindings only available with -std=c++17 or -std=gnu++17
     for (auto [_val, id] : ch)
```

What will be the equivalent C++ 14 code for the above line.

Comment: If there was an "equivalent" statement, you wouldn't need that. You have to store the object and extract the members normally. And that depends on what `ch` is.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of the reason structured bindings were added to C++ was because there was no clean way to emulate them in the existing language.

For a few, rather restricted situations, you can use `std::tie` to emulate structured bindings to some degree, but it's a loose emulation at best. To even have a hope of working, you need to be extracting values from a `std::pair` or `std::tuple`. You also have to separately define variables for the two (or more) items to extract. So, while it can be useful in a few specific cases, but there's almost no chance that it'll work for the task at hand.

And that brings us back to this sort of code being why they added structured bindings to the language. `std::tie` was adequate to show how useful the idea was in general, and under some circumstances it can even be useful in itself--but at least in my opinion, much of its real value was in showing how useful a more general, language-based mechanism would be.